# What are "not so well defined problems" that LISP is supposed to solve?

Tags: lisp

Most people agree that LISP helps to solve problems that are not well defined, or that are not fully understood at the beginning of the project.

"Not fully understood"" might indicate that we don't know what problem we are trying to solve, so the developer refines the problem domain continuously. But isn't this process language independent?

All this refinement does not take away the need for, say, developing algorithms/solutions for the final problem that does need to be solved. And that is the actual work.

So, I'm not sure what advantage LISP provides if the developer has no idea where he's going i.e. solving a problem that is not finalised yet.

Comment: I'd like to note that there's nothing in the question that's *entirely* specific to Lisp.  For example, I think C is better than assembly at solving problems which are not well-defined, and I agree that developing algorithms/solutions still needs to be done in any language, but that does not mean C has no advantage over assembly language.

Comment: Thanks Ken, but the question was intended to ask why this point comes up in every lisp book, while the same claims are not made in favour of C or any other language for that matter. I am not trying to compare the effectiveness of languages here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In AI (Artificial Intelligence) historically Lisp was seen as the AI assembly language. It was used to build higher-level languages which help to work with the problem domain in a more direct way. Many of these domains need a lot of 'knowledge' for finding usable answers.

A typical example is an expert system for, say, oil exploration. The expert system gets as inputs (geological) observations and gives information about the chances to find oil, what kind of oil, in what depths, etc. To do that it needs 'expert knowledge' how to interpret the data. When you start such a project to develop such an expert system it is typically not clear what kind of inferences are needed, what kind of 'knowledge' experts can provide and how this 'knowledge' can be written down for a computer.

In this case one typically develops new languages on top of Lisp and you are not working with a fixed predefined language.

As an example see this old paper about [Dipmeter Advisor](http://ijcai.org/Past%20Proceedings/IJCAI-83-VOL-1/PDF/027.pdf), a Lisp-based expert system developed by Schlumberger in the 1980s.

So, Lisp does not solve any problems. But it was originally used to solve problems that are complex to program, by providing new language layers which should make it easier to express the domain 'knowledge', rules, constraints, etc. to find solutions which are not straight forward to compute.

Answer (score 13):

Lisp (not "LISP") has a number of advantages when you're facing problems that are not well-defined.  First of all, you have a REPL where you can quickly experiment with -- that helps in sketching out quick functions and trying to play with them, leading to a very rapid development cycle.  Second, having a dynamically typed language is working well in this context too: with a statically typed language you need to "design more" before you begin, and changing the design leads to changing more code -- in contrast, with Lisps you just write the code and the data it operates on can change as needed.  In addition to these, there's the usual benefits of a functional language -- one with first class `lambda` functions, etc (eg, garbage collection).

In general, these advantage have been finding their way into other languages.  For example, Javascript has everything that I listed so far.  But there is one more advantage for Lisps that is still not present in other languages -- macros.  This is an important tool to use when your problem calls for a domain specific language.  Basically, in Lisp you can extend the language with constructs that are specific to your problem -- even if these constructs lead to a completely different language.

Finally, you need to plan ahead for what happens when the code becomes more than a quick experiment.  In this case you want your language to cope with "growing scripts into applications" -- for example, having a module system means that you can get a more "serious"
application.  For example, in [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/) you can get your solution separated into such modules, where each can be written in its own language -- it even has a statically typed language which makes it possible to start with a dynamically typed development cycle and once the code becomes more stable and/or big enough that maintenance becomes difficult, you can switch some modules into the static language and get the usual benefits from that.  Racket is actually unique among Lisps and Schemes in this kind of support, but even with others the situation is still far more advanced than in non-Lisp languages.

Comment: ot: congrats on 10k @EliBarzilay.

Answer (score 2):

The "big" win with a language that allows for incremental development is that you (typically) has a read-eval-print loop (or "listener" or "console") that you interact with, plus you tend to not need to lose state when you compile and load new code.

The ability to keep state around from test run to test run means that lengthy computations that are untouched by your changes can simply be kept around instead of being re-computed.

This allows you to experiment and iterate faster. Being able to iterate faster means that exploration is less of a hassle. Very useful for exploratory programming, something that is typical with dealing with less well-defined problems.